# How can I specify that a path component is optional using zsh globbing?

Tags: zsh, wildcards

Say I have the following directory structure:

```
% tree foo 
foo
├── bar
│   └── baz
└── baz
```

How can I elegantly match both `foo/bar/baz` *and* `foo/baz`? I.e. how can I make the `bar/` component of the path optional?

`foo/*/baz` matches only `foo/bar/baz`, because `foo//baz` is not a valid expansion. I tried using optional groups, but this:

```
% set -o KSH_GLOB
% echo foo/?(bar)/baz
```

also only expands to `foo/bar/baz` for the same reason (`foo//baz` isn't a valid expansion). Having a `/` inside a group is generally illegal according to `zshexpn(1)`, so e.g. `foo/?(bar/)baz` throws an error.

This doesn't seem like a particularly exotic case, but I can't find anything on Google search or SE search about it.

Answer (score 4):

It is a bit of a pain point with ksh and zsh globs. You can use braces:

```
echo foo{,/bar}/baz
echo foo{,/*}/baz    # you probably don't want this one, see below
```

However, braces are not globs, and whether they're close enough depends on exactly what you're doing.

The main issue is which files are guaranteed to exist and what you want to happen if some files don't exist. `foo{,/bar}/baz` expands to the two words `foo/baz` and `foo/bar/baz` whether the files exist or not. With wildcards, by default, `foo{,/*}/baz` errors out if there is no file matching `foo/*/baz`, even if `foo/baz` does exist. You can remedy that with the `N` [globbing flag](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Globbing-Flags):

```
echo foo{/*,}/baz(N)
```

This expands to the list of existing files matching `foo/*/baz` (even if that list is empty), followed by `foo/baz` if it exists. This is equivalent to what you'd get from `foo/(*/|)/baz(N)` if it worked. On the other hand there's no simple equivalent to what `foo/(*/|)/baz` would do: if you want an error if there are no matches, you have to do it yourself, e.g.

```
bazes=(foo{,/*}/baz(N))
if (($#bazes == 0)); then echo >&2 "No bazes are belong to us"; return 1; fi
```

Another difference between braces and globs is that the order in the braces determine the order of the expansion. For example, `echo foo{,/*}/baz(Nom)` always puts `foo/baz` first, regardless of its modification time.

Comment: See also the `cshnullglob` option for the command to fail only if *all* the globs fail to match like in csh.

Answer (score 2):

If it doesn't matter to you if you accidentally match >1 of the "optional" pathname component, you can do:

```
% set -o EXTENDED_GLOB
% echo foo/(bar/)#baz
```

This will match `foo/bar` and `foo/bar/baz`, but it will also match `foo/bar/bar/baz`, etc.

Comment: You could then filter out the `foo/bar/bar/baz` with `foo/(bar/)#baz~*/*/*/*` but that wouldn't stop zsh from looking for them in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't explicitly say if you want the matching files in those two places *only*, or *all* of them in the tree. In case matching all of them is an option, you could use `**`:

```
% mkdir -p foo/{bar,asdf/asdf,}/baz
% echo foo/**/baz       
foo/asdf/asdf/baz foo/bar/baz foo/baz
```

it works in Bash too (with `globstar` enabled):

```
$ shopt -s globstar
$ echo foo/**/baz       
foo/asdf/asdf/baz foo/bar/baz foo/baz
```

(There's some caveats/differences between `**` on zsh and Bash wrt. symlinks in the tree.)